# Spring Views - Combining elements into views

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, web

Currently, in our deployment we have a abstract type Component which represents a part of our Page, basically an element such as a Question, which can have multiple choice, a text box or any other form of answering it, or a Video that users can play, basically a shard of a page that is interchangeable, basically, our design was to have a specific area in our website which would be rendered through a list of Components, we tried at first to have each "Page" object have a List of Components, and each Component would have a method render that would return a Spring View, we thought we could iterate over the list and somehow mash the views together.

We also tried using XSTLViews with no more success, it seems to be more of a design problem and our abuse of the way Spring MVC should be used.

We will really be glad to receive any advice/tips/corrections about how to do it right and maybe some corrections about misconceptions we might have.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're more than half way to a design that uses AJAX to build your page.  You're trying to mash up a bunch of Components into one request.  What if you returned a container page which then requested/inserted a block of html for each URL it was given a render time.  Each of these URLs would refer to a single component.  It might be a performance hit if you are including a lot of these Components, but it seems to fit the design.